# How can I get yum to work without root?

Tags: centos, sudo, root, yum

If I make all folder in the root directory world writable, something like:

`sudo chown 777 -R /`

Would this enable `yum` to work without root privileges? If not, is there a way similar to this to make yum work without root? I do realized `sudo` requires root to begin with, but I have a situation where I'm building something on a system with root and transferring it to another system where I will no longer have root (a [singularity](https://singularity.lbl.gov/) container which I'm transferring to a computer cluster).

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 /` – [bad idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12998/108618).

Comment: Is there a chmod variant where I can get yum to work without sudo and not brick the system?

Comment: You do not need root complete access, you just need root to setup sudo once to allow some given user to run `yum` through `sudo yum` to get root access when running it. Changing permissions on disk as you suggest is the sure direct way to a totally irrecoverable system, not even counting all attacks you open yourself to.